# nonblock command ``Isend'' in mpi4py package cannot make the computation and communication overlap

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

Dear experienced programmers, please read my post with patience. I will appreciate your help sincerely.

I am using mpi4py python package to study the nonblock communication command `Isend` and `Irecv`. I tried to use these two commands to overlap communication and following computation, but the following code shows that no overlaps between computation and communication happens when using `Isend` and `Irecv`. This confused me and I cannot find the meaning of nonblock communication.

In the code, 2 process are created and are named as Rank0  and Rank1. The Rank 0  sends a matrix `Node_r` to Rank 1 and after that  both ranks perform a time-consuming calculation which is irrelevant to `Node_r` . The parameter `S` controls the size of the `Node_r`   and `S_c`  controls the time spent on the computation.

If I use Send and Recv commands. The communication and computation should not have overlap and the total time for each rank should be the sum up of time on each part and simulation results exactly prove this.

If I use `Isend`and `Irecv` , then I am expecting that: since these two commands returns immediately, the computation procedure begin immediately and **at the same time** the data transfer has also began. When each rank has finished computation part, the date transfer  should almost ends and thus the `Test()` or `Wait()` function should not take long time.

However, simulations show that  in nonblock case, the `Test()` or `Wait()`  takes the same time as Send and Recv do. In other word, when the two ranks are doing computations, the communication process cannot be performed and vice versa.

I have tried on a supercomputer (Iridis 5 at University of Southampton) and also on my own work station but no matter I set a big problem size `S`=800,`S_c`=1000(The transfer matrix `Node_r` is 8Gb) or a small case `S`=10, `S_c`=3 (`Node_r` is of 16KB). Using `Isend` and `Irecv` always cannot accelerate the code, i.e. no overlapping actually happens. I paste the `S`=800,`S_c`=1000 code and results:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import time
import random
from sys import getsizeof
from numpy import linalg as LA
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
S =800 # Control the size of matrix Node_r to be sent to Rank1
S_c=1000 #control the time consuming calculation after the data communication 
Maxite =1 # The iteration numbers for task: ``data tranformation-> 
computation'' 
Node_r = np.zeros((4*S,S,S),'float32')
Recv_r = np.zeros((4*S,S,S),'float32')
if rank ==0:
    Node_r = np.zeros((4*S,S,S),'float32')+1.0
    print('Node is of ', getsizeof(Node_r)*1e-3, 'KB')
comm.Barrier()


# Synchronous communication code:
if rank == 0:
    START_rank0 = time.time()
    for i in range(Maxite):
        s_rank0 = time.time()
        req_r = comm.Send( [Node_r, MPI.FLOAT], dest =1, tag =11)
        e1_rank0 = time.time()
        for ii in range(2):
            A = np.random.rand(S_c,S_c)
            tt = LA.eig(A)
        e2_rank0 = time.time()
    END_rank0 = time.time()   
    SendList = [START_rank0,END_rank0,s_rank0,e1_rank0,e2_rank0]     
if rank == 1 :
    START_rank1 = time.time()
    for i in range(Maxite): 
        s_rank1 = time.time()
        recv_r = comm.Irecv([Recv_r, MPI.FLOAT], source=0,tag=11)    
        recv_r.Wait()
        e1_rank1 = time.time()
        for ii in range(2):
            A = np.random.rand(S_c,S_c)
            tt = LA.eig(A)    
        e2_rank1 = time.time()    
    END_rank1 = time.time()   
    RecvList = [START_rank1,END_rank1,s_rank1,e1_rank1,e2_rank1] 
comm.Barrier()

 # Asynchronous communication code:
if rank == 0:
    START2_rank0 = time.time()
    for i in range(Maxite):
        ss_rank0 = time.time()
        req_r = comm.Isend( [Node_r, MPI.FLOAT], dest =1, tag =11)
        req_r.Test()
        ee1_rank0 = time.time()
        for ii in range(2):
            A = np.random.rand(S_c,S_c)
            tt = LA.eig(A)
            req_r.Test()
        ee2_rank0 = time.time()
        if req_r.Test()==False:
            #print('Rank0 Test is False')
            req_r.Wait() 
        ee3_rank0 = time.time() 
    END2_rank0 = time.time()  
    IsendList = [START2_rank0,END2_rank0,ss_rank0,ee1_rank0,ee2_rank0, ee3_rank0]    
if rank == 1 :
    START2_rank1 = time.time()
    for i in range(Maxite): 
        ss_rank1 = time.time()
        recv_r = comm.Irecv([Recv_r, MPI.FLOAT], source=0,tag=11)    
        recv_r.Test()
        ee1_rank1 = time.time()
        for ii in range(2):
            A = np.random.rand(S_c,S_c)
            tt = LA.eig(A)
            recv_r.Test()
        ee2_rank1 = time.time() 
        if recv_r.Test()==False:  
            #print('Rank1 Test is False')
            recv_r.Wait() 
        ee3_rank1 = time.time()
    END2_rank1 = time.time()  
    IrecvList =[START2_rank1,END2_rank1,ss_rank1,ee1_rank1,ee2_rank1,ee3_rank1]
comm.Barrier()
if rank==0:
    print('Send: rank0 Duration',SendList[1]-SendList[0])    
    print('Send: rank0 e1-s Send:',SendList[3]-SendList[2])
    print('Send: rank0 e2-e1 Computation:',SendList[4]-SendList[3]) 
    print('Isend rank0 Duration',IsendList[1]-IsendList[0]) 
    print('Isend rank0 ee1-ss Isend:',IsendList[3]-IsendList[2])
    print('Isend rank0 ee2-ee1 Computation:',IsendList[4]-IsendList[3])
    print('Isend rank0 ee3-ee2 Test/Wait:',IsendList[5]-IsendList[4])    

if rank==1:
    time.sleep(3)
    print('#####################################')
    print('Recv: rank1 Duration',RecvList[1]-RecvList[0])    
    print('Recv: rank1 e1-s Recv:',RecvList[3]-RecvList[2])
    print('Recv: rank1 e2-e1 Computation:',RecvList[4]-RecvList[3])     
    print('Irecv rank1 Duration',IrecvList[1]-IrecvList[0]) 
    print('Irecv rank1 ee1-ss Isend:',IrecvList[3]-IrecvList[2])
    print('Irecv rank1 ee2-ee1 Computation:',IrecvList[4]-IrecvList[3])
    print('Irecv rank1 ee3-ee2 Test/Wait:',IrecvList[5]-IrecvList[4])
```

The results are:

```
('Node is of ', 8192000.1280000005, 'KB')

('Send: rank0 Duration', 17.594741106033325)
('Send: rank0 e1-s Send:', 5.696147918701172)
('Send: rank0 e2-e1 Computation:', 11.898576974868774)
('Isend rank0 Duration', 17.708693027496338)
('Isend rank0 ee1-ss Isend:', 0.00017595291137695312)
('Isend rank0 ee2-ee1 Computation:', 11.87893009185791)
('Isend rank0 ee3-ee2 Test/Wait:', 5.8295629024505615)

('Recv: rank1 Duration', 17.276994943618774)
('Recv: rank1 e1-s Recv:', 5.695960998535156)
('Recv: rank1 e2-e1 Computation:', 11.581011056900024)
('Irecv rank1 Duration', 17.708734035491943)
('Irecv rank1 ee1-ss Isend:', 3.814697265625e-05)
('Irecv rank1 ee2-ee1 Computation:', 17.708672046661377)
('Irecv rank1 ee3-ee2 Test/Wait:', 1.6927719116210938e-05)
```

It can be seen that no matter `Test()` or `Wait()` are perfomed, the communication time is always about 5.5s and the computation time is about 11.5s thus the total time is always 17s.

Is there is a way to reduce the total time in `Isend/Irecv` case, making it smaller than 17s?

I have considered about the possible reason is the `Node_r` is so big that the Isend and Irecv have to perform in an synchronous way, as described in the paper `Understanding the Behavior and Performance of Non-blocking Communications in MPI`but I found that even in the tiny case, the overlapping is not obvious.

I appreciate all kind of suggestions from you.

Comment: What you are looking for is a MPI progress thread in your MPI library. This is vendor/version/interconnect specific and you should consult the documentation of the MPI library `mpi4py` was built on top of.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Can you elaborate? Why is OP looking for that particular thing?

Comment: What the OP is looking for is the textbook definition of a MPI progress thread. Without it, a correct implementation of the standard is to have non blocking subroutines do nothing until an other MPI subroutine such as `MPI_Wait()` is invoked, and this is likely what the OP is experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments! I am sorry I do not fully understand your point. I found that  result on `Irecv rank1 ee2-ee1 Computation:', 17.708672046661377` suggests that MPI.Test()  in the computation part also take the same time as synchronous case do. Does this mean that the computation and communication in MPI actually cannot be overlapped to each other? This seems to be conflict to MPI document. If it can be overlap, would you please give me a detailed example on it? Thank you very much!

Comment: It will overlap if your MPI library features a progress thread (that is not mandated by the MPI standard). `MPI_Test()` does progress communications when invoked.

Comment: Ok I see! So I understand why you ask me to look into MPI progress thread. Would you please give me a demo on how to make the MPI library features a progress thread. I have found that there is a mpi4py.features package that provides high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables on a pool of workers. However, I find that in this package, there is no direct command on Isend and Irecv. So, would you please give me a more detailed instruction on how to use Isend and Irecv command to achieve an overlap between communication and computation? As a beginner, I am a slow learner...

Comment: The progress thread, if any, is implemented by the MPI library  `mpi4py` is built on top of. If you use Open MPI 4 on a single node, you'll get the progress thread.